# Will a dino gain experience while being near combat but not in it?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I want to have a Pteranodon sitting on top of a platformed Pracer gaining xp without having to be engaged in combat.

Is this effective at all? Are there other ways to have dino passively gain experience that are effective?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://steamcommunity.com/app/346110/discussions/0/535152511377156419/#c535152511377352588 does this help?

Comment: @Tyrmos Ya there is a bunch of good info there.